# Timestamp from Date and Time

Tags: timestamp, logstash, teradata

I need to fetch some data form Teradata database with logstash. In order to get only the newest data I want to use `logstash :sql_last_value` set to tracking column TS, timestamp type. I am stuck with getting timestamp value from database.

On teradata forum found an idea:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + ((CURRENT_TIME - TIME '00:00:00') HOUR TO SECOND(0));
```

No matter how I try to format time database it always returns me an error connected to TS field (usually time part). This works fine with above 'current' parameters, but I can’t get it work with real values from database.
Example fields: `"datefld" => "2018-04-15"`, `"timefld" => 125318.01` (12:53:18 after format).

Any idea how to get a timestamp for latter use it as an argument in `WHERE`?

SQL statement, as it is now:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DateFld AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + ((TimeFld - TIME '00:00:00') HOUR TO SECOND(0)) as TS,
    DateFld (format 'YYYY-MM-DD')(CHAR (10)),
    TimeFld,
    TimeFld (format '99:99:99') (CHAR (8))as TimeFldF,
    some_other_fields
FROM something
WHERE TS > DATE :sql_last_value
ORDER BY DateFld asc,TimeFld asc
```

Answer (score 0):

`datefld` is a DATE and `timefld` is a DECIMAL?

```
Cast(DateFld AS TIMESTAMP(0)) +
-- numeric -> string -> interval
Cast((TimeFld (FORMAT '99:99:99') (CHAR (8))) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND)
```

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, as we got view with already prepared timestamp column, we have successfully finished our task. Still, regarding your effort, I finally managed to check it. Unfortunately, I got rejected with some SQL syntax error. Is this:    ‘-- numeric -> string -> interval’   part of co nversion syntax or a comment?

Comment: It's a comment, data is converted from a numeric value to a string and then to an interval